# Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'Map<String, dynamic>' which excludes null

Tags: flutter, firebase, flutter-layout, dart-null-safety

I am trying to populate 2 values in my user profile. The values are name and email. I have implemented a function getCurrentUser which uses firebase authentication to get the current signed in user. I then use the uid for the user to query my users database were the name and email is stored.

Inside the function, if I print current user I get the users instance returning with values name, email and isStudent. When running my app is m getting the following error in the console "Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'Map<String, dynamic>' which excludes null." I also get an error on the phone UI saying "LateInitializationError: Field 'name' has not been initialized"

Any advice on this is much appreciated!

I have attached the screenshot of the error and code snippet including variables,function and the variable call to display the values.

[image]

[image]

```
final _firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
late User loggedInUser;

class MenuLecturerScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'menu_lecturer';

  @override
  _MenuLecturerScreenState createState() => _MenuLecturerScreenState();
}

class _MenuLecturerScreenState extends State<MenuLecturerScreen> {
  final messageTextController = TextEditingController();
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  late String messageText;
  //String name = 'Eoin Irwin';
  //String email = 'irwin-e14@ulster.ac.uk';
  late String name;
  late String email;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getCurrentUser();
  }

  void getCurrentUser() async {
    try {
      final user = _auth.currentUser;

      await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("users")
          .doc(user?.uid)
          .get()
          .then((value) {
        final Map<String, dynamic>? currentUser = value.data();
        email = currentUser!['email'];
        name = currentUser!['name'];
        print(currentUser);
      });


      //print(FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("users").doc(user?.uid).get());

      if (user != null) {
        loggedInUser = user;
        print(loggedInUser.email);
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  signOut() async {
    await _auth.signOut();
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, WelcomeScreen.id);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var drawerHeader = UserAccountsDrawerHeader(
      accountName: Text(name),
      accountEmail: Text(email),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a async method. And after getting data you are not using setState to update the UI.

```dart
  await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("users")
          .doc(user?.uid)
          .get()
          .then((value) {
        final Map<String, dynamic>? currentUser = value.data();
        email = currentUser!['email'];
        name = currentUser!['name'];
        print(currentUser);
        setState((){});
      });
```

Also initially name, messageText and email are  null. better use nullable data here

```dart
   String? messageText;
   String? name;
   String? email;
```

Reading map can provide null, for safe case accept null data

```dart
email = currentUser?['email'];
name = currentUser?['name'];
```

And while using it do

```
Text(name??"")
```

Future takes some time to fetch data until then variables are null .

Comment: Thanks for the information I am new to flutter and firebase this helped get the solution working in the profile views on my app

Comment: Glad to help you out. You can also check more about [async-await](https://dart.dev/codelabs/async-await) and on [yt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmTCmDMi4BY)

Answer (score 1):

By adding a ? You mentioned that the map can be null but then if you added ! You are mentioning that is not null and has a value.. try adding ? Instead

```dart
   final Map<String, dynamic>?currentUser = value.data();
        email = currentUser?['email']??"";
        name = currentUser?['name']??"";
        print(currentUser);
```

Edit

```dart
String name = "";
String email = "";
```

Comment: The map should never be null as at this screen the user is already logged in so should be a user when fetching from firestore authentication. I am then getting this user from the user table using the uid to get the record which is used to store further details about the user. The user should always be in the Users table as at login a similar process occurs only to check the type of user instead of getting the name and email. I tried changing to ? but still getting the same error

Comment: The main issue seems to be from name not being initialised, I have attached a screenshot to the bottom of my original question above

Comment: Can you add the error message here please

Comment: The build is using the name and email. So keep it empty at start. Once you get the value from firebase set the name and email and set state